# DOM Childnodes Output the same with Parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Why does these codes produce the same console output.

html output:
Swim

Bike

Run

The first one should not output the p tags text content.

## 1

```
var sports = document.getElementById('sports');
console.log(sports.childNodes);
```

## 2

```
var sports = document.getElementById('sports');
console.log(sports);
```

html excerpt:

```
<section id="sports">
        <p class="swim">Swim</p>
        <p id="bike">Bike</p>
        <p>Run</p>
    </section
```

Comment: Can we see the html too?

Comment: They don't. https://jsfiddle.net/ha62cLwe/ The first one is a NodeList, the second one is a document object (and it's contents.)

Comment: In the second one, the variable `sports` just refers to the `<section id="sports">` DOM object, but when you do `console.log(sports)`, the `console.log()` implementation chooses to show you that DOM element and it's contents.  This is just how `console.log()` is implemented.

Comment: by the way only html tags can be nodes?

Comment: all html tags are nodes, but not all nodes are html tags... there are text nodes, comment nodes, etc

Answer (score 0):

They don't produce same result as suggested by @Observer

"The childNodes property returns a collection of a node's child nodes, as a NodeList object."

Comment: I was referring to console.log output by the html file.